# How to zip a file to a certain directory

Tags: linux, command-line, zip

I've googled this issue and I can't find anything.

I'm trying to zip the contents of my htdocs, and so far it's great, but the zipped file always saves in /home, which over times gets annoying.

```
$ zip derp.zip -r /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

How can I add onto the command to send the zipped file to /home/brackson/Desktop?

Comment: Just full path the name. aka /home/brackson/Desktop/derp.zip

Comment: Have you tried `zip /home/brackson/Desktop/derp.zip -r /opt/lampp/htdocs` or alternatively, make sure your current directory is /home/brackson/Desktop before running the command?

Comment: Can we all get a CheckMark =)

Comment: Thanks Josh R. I would mark your answer as accepted, but I don't think that I can for comments.

Comment: Take the chance and get the reward!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
zip /home/brackson/Desktop/derp.zip -r /opt/lampp/htdocs/*
```

Sources:
http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_zip.htm
[Experience](https://superuser.com/)